# Erklärung des Begriffs "freier finaler Infinitiv"

Tags: infinitive

Vor einigen Monaten hatten wir eine Diskussion über den Absentiv. Darin wurde der Text [Kein Absentiv im Deutschen](http://www.sprachforschung.org/ickler/index.php?show=news&id=1278), in dem sich Ickler an selbigem abarbeitet.

> Sucht man nach einer Gemeinsamkeit sämtlicher Beispiele, die nicht vorab auf „Abwesenheit“ festgelegt ist, so stößt man auf den finalen Infinitiv. Er geht wahrscheinlich auf den Akkusativ eines Verbalsubstantivs zurück. In der älteren Sprache war er verbreiteter, heute wird das finale Verhältnis oft durch die Präposition zu oder eine Konstruktion mit um zu verdeutlicht.
>   „...it gradually became more common to place before the infinitive the preposition *zu* or later also *um zu*, which brought out the idea of purpose more clearly.“ (Curme 1922/1964:275)

Er nennt dazu ein Beispiel:

> Der freie finale Infinitiv ohne zu ist heute recht selten. Weder in Eisenbergs Zusammenstellung der Infinitivkonstruktionen (1999:339) noch im Handbuch der deutschen Wortarten (Hoffmann 2007) wird er erwähnt. Immerhin kommt er vor:
>   *Aber meistens sitze ich natürlich im italienischen Eiscafé Teenager beobachten.* (Eckhard Henscheid: Geht in Ordnung – Sowieso – Genau. Frankfurt 1979:20)

Die Frage: was ist der „freie finale Infinitiv“ im Gegensatz zum von einem Verb regierten Infinitiv („Ich *werde* heute eine Pizza *essen*“)? Welche weiteren Beispiele gibt es hierfür?

Comment: ich verstehe die Frage nicht wirklich. "Freier Infinitiv" heißt, dass das Verb unabhängig ist und dennoch im Infinitiv steht. Beispiel: "Bitte anklopfen.". Was genau möchtest du wissen, was hat das mit den Texten zu tun, und warum bringst du zum Abschluss zwei Beispiele für einen "zu"-Infinitiv wo ein "um" fehlt.Ich bin verwirrt.

Comment: Die Frage ist: was meint Ickler mit "freier Infinitiv"?

Comment: Na, dass der Infinitiv nicht an ein Verb oder ein "zu" gebunden ist. Er gibt ja auch ein Beispiel. Was hat das aber mit deinen beiden letzten Beispielen zu tun? Weder mit noch ohne "um" handelt es sich um "freie" Infinitive.

Comment: @Emanuel: Wenn ich verstünde, was "freier finaler Infinitiv" genau bedeutet bzw. was Ickler meint, würde ich hier nicht fragen.

Comment: Aber ich hab's doch gesagt. Hier würden sicher gerne viele helfen, aber vielleicht solltest du dann mal klar machen, warum die Definition, die ich gegeben habe, dich nicht befriedigt. Zudem hast du dich immer noch nicht dazu geäussert, was du mit den beiden Beispielen am Ende illustrieren willst. Sie haben mit dem Thema herzlich enig zu tun. Da du offenbar keinen Bedarf siehst, deine Frage klarer zu stellen, werde ich jetzt Close voten.

Comment: @Emanuel: Vielleicht solltest Du einfach etwas in der Richtung als Antwort posten.

Comment: Deine Beispiele sollten in der Form "Ich lebe (zu) arbeiten - Ich lebe (,um zu) arbeiten" um klar zu machen, dass du vermutest, es wäre ursprünglich "Ich lebe arbeiten" gewesen und das "zu" oder "um zu" wäre mit der Zeit hinzugekommen.

Comment: @Emanuel: Icklers Beispiel "Ich sitze im Café..." hat wenig mit "Bitte anklopfen" zu tun. Meine Beispiele waren eine Interpretation des Begriffs von mir, die richtig oder falsch sein kann.

Comment: Aber wie kommst du darauf? IN dem Zitat steht ausdrücklich "Der freie Infinitiv ohne zu"... OHNE. Und dann bringst du zwei Beispiele mit "zu". Sorry, aber das macht einfach keinen Sinn für mich. Was mein und Ickler's Beispiel angeht so genügen sie beide meiner Definition... es gibt einen Infinitiv der von nix abhängig ist. Dass sie in sehr unetrschiedlichen Sätzen verwendet werden, ist nicht wichtig.

Comment: @Emanuel: So, die leidige Diskussion um die Beispiele kann nun beendet werden. Ich verstehe den Begriff immer noch nicht und habe nun die Frage klarer formuliert.

Answer (score 5):

"Finaler (= einen Zweck bezeichnender) Infinitiv":

> Ich gehe weg, um einzukaufen.

"Freier finaler Infinitiv":

> Ich gehe einkaufen bzw. ich bin einkaufen

Die Aussage, dass ich weggehen muss, um einzukaufen, wird als bekannt vorausgesetzt. Somit steht der finale Infinitiv für zwei semantische Kategorien: Es wird sowohl die Ortsveränderung (Wo bist du? bzw. Wo gehst du hin?) als auch die beabsichtigte Tätigkeit (Was hast du vor?) damit angezeigt. Diese Kategorien sind komplementär. Wie viel Information damit tatsächlich transportiert wird, hängt vom gemeinsamen Vorwissen von Sender und Empfänger der Mitteilung ab:

"Ich bin einkaufen" kann bedeuten:

> Ich kaufe gerade in dem Laden ein, in dem ich immer einkaufe.

oder z. B.:

> Ich bin nicht im Haus, sondern kaufe gerade irgendwo ein.

Die Wahl des Verbs kann, entsprechendes Vorwissen vorausgesetzt, unterschiedliche Orte bezeichnen:

> Ich bin einkaufen (am gewohnten Ort) / Ich bin shoppen (irgendwo in
>   der Stadt)

Oft hängt es vom Sprecher ab, wie viel örtliche Information enthalten ist:

> Ich bin laufen

Veronika läuft immer den Fluss entlang, also ist sie dort irgendwo unterwegs.
Markus liebt das Laufband im Fitnesscenter, also ist er dort.
Christine entscheidet sich immer spontan, also weiß man nicht, wo sie läuft.

Das Beispiel "Ich sitze … Teenager beobachten" ist in dieser Form natürlich falsch. "Sitzen" und "beobachten" sind so nicht kombinierbar. Es muss entweder heißen "Ich bin Teenager beobachten" oder "Ich sitze im Café, Teenager beobachten".

@ Veredomon*)
Ickler resümiert in seinem Beitrag: *Die Bedeutungskomponente der „Abwesenheit“ ist ein vorhersagbarer Nebeneffekt des finalen Infinitivs in einigen seiner Verwendungen.* Die Kategorie eines "Absentivs" sei daher überflüssig. Das untermauert er nicht gerade mit überzeugenden Beispielen. Dass *Ganz Breslau scheint hier einkaufen zu sein*, anscheinend sein Kronzeugen-Beispiel, keine Abwesenheitsdeutung erlaubt, liegt daran, dass es schlechtes Deutsch ist und "zu sein" einfach weggelassen werden kann (… scheint hier einzukaufen). Die Behauptung, die Antwort auf die Frage *Wo ist er/sie?* könne nicht implizit die Abwesenheit ausdrücken, denn diese sei ja die Voraussetzung für die Frage, finde ich merkwürdig. Der Fragende findet die fragliche Person zwar im Augenblick nicht vor, kann aber die Antwort nicht vorhersehen, die lauten könnte: Er war nur auf dem WC oder auf dem Balkon, sie ist oben, er repariert gerade sein Motorrad, er will niemanden sehen, sie ist im Haus nebenan. "Sie ist shoppen" ist hier m. E. eine andere Aussagekategorie, die substanziell mehr Information enthält, wenn das entsprechende Vorwissen vorhanden ist. Ob man dies am Kriterium der Abwesenheit festmachen will und es "Absentiv" nennt oder nicht, ist eine Frage des Standpunkts. Es ist ja auch nicht gesagt, dass die Abwesenheit der Hauptinformationsinhalt eines "Absentivs" sein muss, sie kann ja genauso gut das auslösende Motiv für die Aussage sein — was normalerweise in Form einer Frage der Fall ist, weil selten jemand beim Einkaufen "ich bin einkaufen, ich bin einkaufen" vor sich hinmurmelt. Gerade Icklers Beispiel "Ich war schon lange nicht mehr Klavierspielen" ist verräterisch, weil es implizit aussagt, dass das Klavierspielen woanders stattfindet: Ansonsten würde man sagen "Ich habe schon lange nicht mehr Klavier gespielt". Die erweiterten Beispiele von König, die Ickler zitiert, zeigen ebenfalls diese charakteristische Einheit von Ort- und Tätigkeitsangabe.

Die Frage bezog sich letztlich auf die Unterschiede zwischen finalem und freiem finalem Infinitiv. Ersterer funktioniert in Form von *Tätigkeit + "um zu" + Absicht*, letzterer lässt "um zu" weg. Ickler zitiert dafür nur das eher schiefe Café-Beispiel, Beispiele mit "machen" und "lassen" diskutiert er nicht (*Ich mache sie lachen*, *Ich lasse ihn suchen*), die zugegeben problematisch sind, weil sie sich nur mühsam oder gar nicht in eine "um zu"-Konstruktion auflösen lassen. Alles andere sind für ihn reine Infinitive nach Verben der Fortbewegung bzw. dem Weglassen solcher Verben bzw. ihrem Ersatz durch "wollen", "sein", "müssen" etc. Warum Ickler diesen Unterschied überhaupt macht und die von ihrer Aussagefunktion her, siehe oben, sehr spezifischen Konstruktionen mit "sein" + Tätigkeit nicht als freie finale Infinitive anerkennt, bleibt für mich nach wie vor offen — vielleicht habe ich es auch nicht richtig verstanden. 
*) war eigentlich als Antwort auf Veredomons Kommentar gedacht, leider zu lang für die Kommentarfunktion

Comment: Hmm. Das wäre dann aber der Absentiv, dessen Existenz Ickler gerade verneint. So wie ich ihn verstanden habe, sagt er unter anderem, „Der Absentiv ist keine grammatische Kategorie, sondern nur ein freier finaler Infinitiv“; diese Argumentation ergäbe aber nur dann Sinn, wenn es den „freien finalen Infinitiv“ ausserhalb des Absentivs gibt, als ein generelles Phänomen. So wie teilweise auch gesagt wird, dass das Zustandspassiv keine grammatikalische Kategorie, sondern „nur“ eine Kopula sei; dies ergibt Sinn, weil es eine Kopula ausserhalb des ZP gibt und ZP wie eine Kopula aufgebaut ist.

Answer (score 0):

Das Beispiel mit im Cafe sitzen Teenager beobachten kommt mit nicht wie Standardsprache vor. Ich habe das Gefühl, das ist gesprochene Umgangssprache und mehr in Norddeutschland zuhause.
Ich spreche mehr süddeutsche Sprache und würde nie so reden. Ich würde sagen:
Meistens sitze ich im Cafe und beobachte Teenager.